# If the format of a data is slightly broken, is it still possible to determine its filetype?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation, csv

I have a random text data, and I need to determine its filetype, such as .xls, .csv, .tsv, .json and .html. Currently I am using a brute force to parse the file against all different format.

My problem occurs when the file is slightly broken, and will fail in the parsing process. In these cases, is there a reasonably good heuristics  that can guess the filetype, so that I can further "lint" the data according to this format?

I am using node.js, in case there is already a library for that. I am open to solution outside of node.js.

I tried to use mmmagic, but it only return "text/plain", instead of the information I need (.tsv, .json, .xml), sample code in livescript:

```
useMagic = (res)->
    buf = new Buffer res.body
    magic = new mmmagic.Magic! ##return UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
    #magic = new mmmagic.Magic mmmagic.MAGIC_MIME ## return text/plain; charset=utf-8
    #magic = new mmmagic.Magic mmmagic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE ##text/plain



    err, magicalres <- magic.detect buf
    magicalres |> console.log 


url = "https://sheethub.com/data.fda.gov.tw/%E4%B8%8D%E7%AC%A6%E5%90%88%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81%E8%B3%87%E8%A8%8A%E8%B3%87%E6%96%99%E9%9B%86/i/96/%E7%B3%AF%E7%B1%B3?page=1&format=json"
err, res, body <- request {"url": url, "encoding": null}
result = res |> useMagic
```

I am adding the compiled javascript code, maybe this will be easier:

```
request = require('request');
mmmagic = require('mmmagic');


useMagic = function(res){
  var buf, magic;
  buf = new Buffer(res.body);
  magic = new mmmagic.Magic();
  return magic.detect(buf, function(err, magicalres){
    return console.log(
    magicalres);
  });
};
url = "https://sheethub.com/data.fda.gov.tw/%E4%B8%8D%E7%AC%A6%E5%90%88%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81%E8%B3%87%E8%A8%8A%E8%B3%87%E6%96%99%E9%9B%86/i/96/%E7%B3%AF%E7%B1%B3?page=1&format=json";
request({
  "url": url,
  "encoding": null
}, function(err, res, body){
  var result;
  return result = useMagic(
  res);
});
```

I have been using a combination of methods including `res.headers['content-type']`, but there are still [cases](http://cloud.culture.tw/e_upload_ccacloud/ntlacW.csv) were all method fails.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tired the [mmmagic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmmagic) module, which provides a binding to *libmagic*?

It allows inspection of a file for known "magic" identifiers. Typically it only needs access to the first few bytes of a file to do this.

I guess this approach might itself be considered "brute force" but at least it relies on a well-known and well-tested library.

**Update after initial suggestion of mmmagic failed to deliver the magic:**

If you're always requesting your data via HTTP(S) using the *request* module then the response headers may provide a hint:

```
// returns 'text/json' for your data.fda.gov.tw sample
var mimeType = res.headers['content-type'];
```

Failing that, the [fsql](https://metacpan.org/pod/fsql) Perl module contains [regex-based logic for determining if text is CSV, TSV, YAML or JSON](https://github.com/perlancar/perl-App-fsql/blob/master/bin/fsql#L151-L166) that might be suitable for repurposing in your own code.

Comment: This library seems to be reasonably lightweight and looks like it returns the stuff you'll need :)

Comment: Thanks, I just added my sample code using mmagic. It only gives me information such as "plan/text". Maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: I edited the question, so I am using `res.headers['content-type']`, but there are still [cases](http://cloud.culture.tw/e_upload_ccacloud/ntlacW.csv) when this doesn't work. Thanks for https://github.com/perlancar/perl-App-fsql/blob/master/bin/fsql#L151-L166 I am checking whether it works in my case. Thanks!